# DAC Signal to AC?

Tags: dac, level-shifting, stm32f3

I am producing a sine wave signal from STM32F3 through DAC. but since micro-controllers can not produce negative output so my output limits to positive half only. but in my application i need signal like with negative half also. Please guide me about converting a DC signal to AC. i also put capacitor in series with the output but it did not work perfectly either, leaving most part of the signal in the positive half. Also due to some reasons i can not afford to put op-amp in the circuit. So please refer some circuits or technique which does not require op-amp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Centre the sinewave at the midpoint numerically in the DAC's range. Then use a capacitor for removing the DC offset. The amplitude of the sinewave will have to halve to ensure it does not clip. Try and get the DAC output like this: -

[image]

Can you see that the zero point for the sine wave is now at half full scale? RC filter: -

[image]

Choose R so that it doesn't load the DAC output too much - maybe 10Kohms and choose C so that the cut-off frequency (fc) is lower than the lowest frequency you want to output: -

Fc = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am doing the same the center point of my wave is at 2048 of 12 bit (4096) DAC. can you please prescribe capacitor value in order to remove the DC offset?

Comment: See adds to answer.

Comment: @hamza_iiee if you are happy with this answer would you consider formally accepting it. If you need further clarification, please ask.